# remove docker repository on remote docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

### Given a docker registry managing multiple docker repositories, how do I delete one of the repositores?

Given docker repositories `repo1` and `repo2`.

```
$ curl -X GET localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["repo1", "repo2"]}
```

I want to remove repository `repo1` so `_catalog` does not list `repo1`, like

```
$ curl -X GET localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["repo2"]}
```

Currently, repository `repo1` only has the default `"latest"` image tag

```
$ curl -X GET localhost:5000/v2/repo1/tags/list
{"name":"repo1","tags":["latest"]}
```

(Maybe that affects being able to delete `repo1`?)

---

#### I have tried...

The following commands returned `404 page not found`:

```
$ curl -X DELETE localhost:5000/v1/repositories/repo1
$ curl -X DELETE localhost:5000/v2/repositories/repo1
$ curl -X DELETE localhost:5000/v2/repo1
```

And the following returned `{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED","message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}`

```
$ curl -X DELETE localhost:5000/v2/repo1/manifests/latest
```

#### Using versions

The remote docker-registry is `registry/2.0`

```
curl -vX GET localhost:5000/v2/
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
...
```

and

```
$ /bin/registry github.com/docker/distribution v2.4.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use the Docker Registry API V2 to delete an image from a private registry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033055/how-can-i-use-the-docker-registry-api-v2-to-delete-an-image-from-a-private-regis)

Comment: @BMitch SImilar but different in that I want the repository `repo1` to not be listed in the `_catalog`.

Comment: Did you see the answer pointing to: https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#delete

Answer (score 35):

by enabling DELETE API you're only able to delete the TAG not the whole repository from `v2/_catalog`.

in order to do this, you should:

**1. enable DELETE API:**

1.1 by `config.yml` : `storage.delete.enabled:true`

1.2 by env: `-e REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true`

**2. get the tag reference** via `GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<tag>`
 (don't forget to have Header `Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json`).

in response headers, you have `docker-content-digest: <sha256:xxx>`

**3. send**  `DELETE /v2/<name>/manifests/<sha256:xxx>`

**4. run garbage collector:** `bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml`

**5. remove files:** `rm -r /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/<name>/<tag>`

**finally:** now you can see

`curl -X GET localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["repo2", "repo3"]}`

**ps.**

consequences of 5: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2983#issuecomment-530251232

Comment: Please note that this **doesn't delete a single tag** since multiple tags can refere to one image that is identified by the digest.

Comment: where is bin/registry ? @negar

Answer (score 6):

There is no API to delete a repository. You need to delete individual tags or manifests within the repository. And until OCI's distribution-spec, there wasn't even an API to delete tags, you need to delete image manifests by digest, which deletes all tags pointing to that same digest.

To delete manifests, first ensure that you have enabled deletion according to [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#delete) before attempting anything. In your configuration of the registry, you would add the following section:

```
delete:
  enabled: true
```

That can also be set by starting your registry container with the `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true` environment variable specified.

Then you can call the manifest delete API:

```
curl -X DELETE \
     -s "https://registry.example.org/v2/${repo}/manifests/${sha}"
```

If you want a wrapper around this to handle auth, and even support tag deletion, see [regclient's regctl](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/) CLI that I've written. Google's crane and RedHat's skopeo may also provide this.

Once the manifests are deleted, you still need to clean the other items the manifest pointed to with a garbage collection (this needs to be done when no writes are occurring):

```
docker exec registry /bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml --delete-untagged
```

That said, you'll still reach the point where the repository itself is not removed. You can delete the entire directory from the filesystem of the registry. But I would recommend getting support for this implemented from the project. See [this issue](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/2314) for more details on getting the capability added to the official registry image.

Comment: +1 I made the recommended change.  Now I get

*`$ curl -X DELETE localhost:5000/v2/repo1/manifests/latest`* results in
*`{"errors":[{"code":"DIGEST_INVALID","message":"provided digest did not match uploaded content"}]}`*.

Comment: To delete an image, you need to specify the digest, not the tag. See https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#deleting-an-image