# Remove Empty Docker Regstry Repositories

Tags: docker, docker-registry

For a couple of days I'm looking for a way to remove empty repositories from my private Docker registry.

I don't succeed at all and see dozens of 3rd party scripts that overcome some issues people have with the default garbage collection.

My idea is to have a cron running with a script that just removes repositories where no images are in anymore. As the API doesn't seem to support that I'm looking for something else where people might already have found a solution to do so.

Comment: I think this would be better resolved by working the issue on the product: https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/2314

Comment: Also I believe this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43666910/596285

Comment: @BMitch that is wish by lots of people, the question is why they don't fix it. It's some sort of a duplicate but pretty outdated.